# Create C# global object which is initialized with another object

Tags: c#, class, global

In my code i have several object I use in various classes.
Instead of passing them as argument each time I use those classes I want to create a global class containing all those "global" objects/classes.

The problem is that they all relay on one dynamic object, ideally I would have defined my global class like this:

```
{
    public static class Globals
    {
        public static dynamic VaProxy;
        public static Dictionary<string, CallBack> CallBacks;
        public static Dictionary<string, Airport> AirportsData;

        static Globals()
        {
            CallBacks = vaProxy.SessionState["CallBacks"];
            AirportsData = vaProxy.SessionState["airportsData"];
        }
    }
}
```

The problem of course is that vaProxy is not defined and I cannot use a constructor which object like this:

```
static Globals(dynamic vaProxy)...
```

So how can I define this global class.object and access it still?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `Extensions`.

Define an interface (as a marker) and use it for all your classes and then use your `class Globals` to define your common methods and properties. I don't see another way because your "Globals" is a static class.